# How to delete external Matplot frame in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm using Matplot to plot a graph inside the Tkinter GUI. Could someone maybe tell me how to get rid of the external frame (in grey/or black when not activated) that is automatically created?

Here is a picture of my graph

[image: Example plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the highlightthickness and borderwidth of the underlying canvas.

something like:

```
frame = Frame(master)
fig = Figure(**options)
figagg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, frame)
canvas = figagg.get_tk_widget()
canvas.config(bd=0, highlightthickness=0) # <---
canvas.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
```